# Quiver polar plot returns scatterplot instead of arrows, when it shouldn't

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

```
r = np.linspace(0.1,1,11)
theta = np.linspace(-alpha,alpha,11)
radius_matrix, theta_matrix = np.meshgrid(r,theta)

u_radial = -q*(1/radius_matrix)*u_sol[0]
u_theta = theta_matrix*[0 for x in range(len(u_sol[0]))]

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta_matrix, radius_matrix, u_radial, u_theta) #color='r', 
ls='none', marker='.'
plt.show()
```

I am trying to make a plot of a velocity field (same as vector field) using numpys quiver function. The velocity field is written

[image]

where q is just an arbitrary constant and r is the distance to the origin. Now, to plot this in a polar coordinate system I create two meshgrids radius_matrix and theta_matrix, as seen in my code (line three). Together these meshgrids form a polar coordinate plane, with r on the horizontal axis and theta on the vertical axis (at least I think) and each point should have a vector arrow corresponding to the equation above.

So for that to happen I define u_radial and u_theta, which are the vector components in radial and angluar direction, resp.. The variable u_sol[0] contains f(theta) (as seen in the equation) for 11 different theta points, and I thought that this would give the correct vectorcomponent, but it doesnt. Why not?

I am expecting something like this, that the arrow shrinks when I get close to the edge for a single value of r. I just want this but for more values of r. This is the data of my u_sol[0] vector:

```
u_sol[0] = [4.68520269e-26 1.54380741e+00 2.74550730e+00 3.60503630e+00
4.12217780e+00 4.29651250e+00 4.12741184e+00 3.61407419e+00
2.75560427e+00 1.55113610e+00 3.84028608e-18]
```

When I plot this, I get something worse, see the figure below. What happend to the arrows? And why are there colors all of a sudden?

Best regards SimpleP.
[image]

Comment: In how far is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623210/how-do-i-use-quiver-in-python-for-polar)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That's true, no different since I got a great answer on the last one. I was a bit impatient, thought that I had formulated my question badly since no one answered. Still, there are one thing that remains to be fixed: How I add the u[0] as "weights" to the vectors/arrows. Do you know?